# Laravel Livewire: nav menu on all pages except home page

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a Livewire application. I want to display the navbar on all pages except the first page.

I have the following:

Routes file:

```
Route::get('/', Home::class)->name('home');
Route::get('/products', Product::class)->name('products');
```

Livewire component Home:

```
public function render() {
   return view('components.home');
}
```

Livewire component Product:

```
public function render() {
   return view('components.products');
}
```

Resource file for `layouts.app`:

```
<body class="bg-white">
    @include('layouts.navigation')
    {{ $slot }}
    @livewireScripts
</body>
```

Resource file for `components.home`:

```
  <div class="mx-auto w-full m-16 px-6 lg:px-8">
  ...
  </div>
```

Resource file for `components.products`:

```
<div class="mx-auto w-full m-16 px-6 lg:px-8">
  <ul role="list" class="mx-auto mt-6 grid max-w-2xl grid-cols-1 gap-x-8 gap-y-16 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:mx-0 lg:max-w-none lg:grid-cols-4">
       @foreach($products as $product)
            ...show products
       @endforeach
  </ul>
</div>
```

I also have a `navigation` component:

```
<nav x-data="{ open: false }" class="bg-gray-800">
  <div class="mx-auto w-full px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
   ....
   ....
  </div>
</nav>
```

Because I added the `@include` in the layouts file, this displays the navigation on all pages.
As I want the navigation to appear on all pages except the home page, I removed the `@include('layouts.navigation')` from the layouts file and I added it to the other pages as follows:

```
@include('layouts.navigation')

<div class="mx-auto w-full m-16 px-6 lg:px-8">
  <ul role="list" class="mx-auto mt-6 grid max-w-2xl grid-cols-1 gap-x-8 gap-y-16 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:mx-0 lg:max-w-none lg:grid-cols-4">
       @foreach($products as $product)
            ...show products
       @endforeach
  </ul>
</div>
```

This results in

> Livewire only supports one HTML element per component. Multiple root
> elements detected for component

Anything else I can do to make it appear on all pages except the home page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very efficient to manually include your navbar on separate pages. That defeats the whole purpose of the layout.blade.

You can easily fetch the current route using `Route::currentRouteName()`.

Since you're using a full page Livewire component, you *will* have to store the value somewhere, because on subsequent requests the current route will be `livewire.message`. The simplest way would be to make your own component class to extend with base logic:

```php
use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class BaseComponent extends Component
{
    public ?string $currentRoute;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->currentRoute = Route::currentRouteName();
    }
}
```

```php
class Home extends BaseComponent
{
    public function mount()
    {
        parent::mount();
        // Your own mount logic
    }
}
```

Then it would be simple blade logic:

```html
<body class="bg-white">
    @if($currentRoute !== 'home')
        @include('layouts.navigation')
    @endif
    {{ $slot }}
    @livewireScripts
</body>
```